# Not a valid 2d array google chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have the current code that attempts to build a 2d array for the google charts.

However I get an invalid 2D array error.

What am i doing wrong?  Thank you in advance

```
//Request data
        $.getJSON(api,function(data){

            //Init final array for data
            var finalData = [["SessionLength"]];

            //Iterate over results
            for (var key in data){

                //Get the key pair
                 var keyPair = [key, parseInt(data[key])];

                //Add to array
                 finalData.push(keyPair);
             }

            // Create the data table.
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(finalData);

            // Set chart options
            var options = {'title':'Average session length',
                'width':400,
                'height':400};

            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        });
```

This is the JSON

```
{"2013-8-5":"13.5","2013-7-29":"19.7","2013-8-4":"12.2","2013-8-3":"14.1","2013-8-2":"10.1","2013-7-31":"15.1","2013-7-30":"17.4","2013-8-6":"16.0","2013-8-1":"15.0"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `finalData` array's first element needs to be a 2-element array:

```
var finalData = [['Date', 'SessionLength']];
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your doing wrong the 2D array initialization
You should just write

```
var finalData = [];
```

because `var finalData = [["SessionLength"]];` is creating an array which have single element as ["SessionLength"] which is one element array, then you are adding arrays which have 2 elements, so actually you get an invalid 2D array like this:

```
[["SessionLength"], ["2013-8-5", "13.5"], ["2013-7-29","19.7"]...]
```